# How to make Firefox 57 to always open new tab from address bar?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, firefox-quantum

Firefox before version 57 allows users to open new tab from address bar using an extension (e.g. TabMixPlus). TabMixPlus is no longer supported. How to make Firefox 57+ to always open new tab from address bar?

(New tab from bookmarks is accessible via `browser.tabs.loadBookmarksInTabs`, but I have not find an `about:config` entry for new tab from url bar, just an [feature request](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=268039) for `browser.tabs.opentabfor.urlbar`.)

**UPDATE:** Firefox 60 added the missing option to about:config.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firefox 60 actually has flag `browser.urlbar.openintab` in `about:config`. Setting it to true accomplishes what you want.
Tried and true.

Comment: `browser.search.openintab` is the corresponding option for the search engine bar, for anyone interested

Answer (score 7):

The only working solution I've found (currently) is an Add-on called "[New Tab from Location Bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-from-location-bar/)" by [Piro](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/user/piro-piro_or/).

The solution by [andy_m](https://superuser.com/users/540779/andy-m) didn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

Workarounds:

- Press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> for the completed URL.
- Press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while clicking on a *link*, or use middle-mouse button.

It would be simpler if these were the same keys, if there are Firefox developers reading this.

As a long-time TabMix Plus user, I really miss this and other features, such as shifting focus to a tab on mouse-hover. Until Firefox WebExtensions is more mature, apparently, that capability is gone. *Sic transit gloria mundi.*

Comment: Is there a way to implement this feature in `userChrome.js`?

Comment: NAFAIK, though there are a number of *static* tab attributes I've modified there (e.g. width, colors etc.).

Answer (score 4):

This feature was added in Firefox 60, cf. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1394304

- open `about:config`
- find `browser.urlbar.openintab`
- double click to flip it to true

Answer (score 2):

The about:config setting only controls pressing "Enter" in the search bar.  It doesn't cause clicking on the right arrow in the search bar to open a new tab.  See:

```
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1170645
```

It took me a while to realize this.

Answer (score 1):

Found [here](http://techdows.com/2017/09/firefox-57-open-bookmarks-in-a-new-tab-preference.html)

1. Visit about:config and proceed by agreeing to the risk button
2. Search **browser.tabs.loadBookmarksInTabs**. Double click on that to change to **true** if found.
   Or right click New >Boolean, enter the preference name as **browser.tabs.loadBookmarksInTabs**. Change its value as **true**, done.